# Improved Euler method and local error

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Given the differential equation $t'=g(x,t)$
>
> 1. Use the improved Euler method by analysing the local error and its stability for the equation $t'=\delta t$, where $\delta$ is a complex
>      number.
> 2. For $t_{n+1}=t_{n-1}+2kg(x_n,t_n)$, analyze its truncation error. Also, similar to part $1$, study its stability for $t'=\phi t$, where
>      this time $\phi$ is a real number.

How will I go about solving this question? Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

I know for a differential equation problem $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ I will use the approximation of the derivative $$y'(t)=\frac{y(t+h)-y(t)}{h}$$ for some small $h$. Then if I let $t_j=t_0+jh$ then $$\frac{y(t_{j+1})-y(t_j)}{h}=f(t_j,y(t_j))$$ leading to $y(t_{j+1})=y(t_j)+hf(t_j,t(t_j))$, which is Euler's method for an ordinary differential equation.

Comment: You should give the equation you would use for the improved Euler method.  Your expression for the regular Euler method is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the regular Euler method, as you say, you have $y(t_{j+1})=y(t_j)+hf(t_j,t(t_j))$  If you expand $y(t)$ in a Taylor series around $t_0$, you have $y(t)=y(t_0)+(t-t_0)y'(t_0)+\frac 12 y''(t-t_0)^2+\ldots$.  Euler's method will give you $y(t_{j+1})=y(t_j)+hy'(t_j)$.  For small steps the error is the lowest order term, $\frac {h^2}2y''(t_0)$

For stability for $y'=\delta t$, this will give $y(t_{j+1})=y(t_j)+(t_{j+1}-t_j)\delta y(t_j)=y(t_j)(1+\delta(t_{j+1}-t_j))$.  If all the steps are the same size, $h$, this becomes $y(t_{j+1})=y(t_j)(1+\delta h)$ with solution $y(t_0+n\Delta t)=y(t_0)(1+\delta h)^n$  If $\delta$ is negative, the solution should decay to zero, but if $h \gt \frac 2{\delta}$ this blows up.

Can you follow this through for the improved Euler method?

Comment: Thank you ! I think I can, I am going to give a try now.

Comment: Mr. Millikan do you know how I can analyze the truncation error for question $2$?

Comment: @user60514:  You should be able to follow what I did in the first paragraph.  Expand $y$ in a Taylor series around $y(t_n)$, apply the stepping algorithm and see which term is the lowest order that doesn't cancel.  If $k$ is the stepsize, I recall that you should find the second derivative term also cancels and the error is third order.